# stack , esp register

Tags: c, assembly

I copy this code from a book. In every comment I put a number and then ask you question(1,2,3,4) related to lines of code commented by that number. Hope its ok.

1) ESP points to these buffer values. WHY dont we see a 0x41 for ´A´ over here ????

2) ESP points to flag variable memory that must contain 31337 which is 0x7a69 in hex. WHY DOES IT INSTEAD CONTAIN THIS NUMBER 0xbffff89c ???

3) Points to previous stack frame pointer, which is this case contains a correct address.

4) Return address. Also correct.

5) Arguments. Also correct values.

So what happens in 1) and 2)? Is it padding?

Thank u very much.

```
void test_function(int a, int b, int c, int d) {
  int flag;
  char buffer[10];
  flag = 31337;
  buffer[0] = 'A';
}

int main() {
  test_function(1, 2, 3, 4);
}


GDB debug session
Breakpoint 2, test_function (a=1, b=2, c=3, d=4) at stack_example.c:5
5 flag = 31337;
(gdb) i r esp ebp eip
esp 0xbffff7c0 0xbffff7c0
ebp 0xbffff7e8 0xbffff7e8
eip 0x804834a 0x804834a <test_function+6>
(gdb) disass test_function
Dump of assembler code for function test_function:
0x08048344 <test_function+0>: push ebp
0x08048345 <test_function+1>: mov ebp,esp
0x08048347 <test_function+3>: sub esp,0x28
0x0804834a <test_function+6>: mov DWORD PTR [ebp-12],0x7a69
0x08048351 <test_function+13>: mov BYTE PTR [ebp-40],0x41
0x08048355 <test_function+17>: leave
0x08048356 <test_function+18>: ret
End of assembler dump.
(gdb) print $ebp-12
$1 = (void *) 0xbffff7dc
(gdb) print $ebp-40
$2 = (void *) 0xbffff7c0
  (gdb) x/16xw $esp  
    0xbffff7c0: 0x00000000 0x08049548 0xbffff7d8 0x08048249  // 1
    0xbffff7d0: 0xb7f9f729 0xb7fd6ff4 0xbffff808 0x080483b9  // 1 
    0xbffff7e0: 0xb7fd6ff4                                   // 1
    0xbffff89c                                               // 2
    0xbffff808                                               // 3
    0x0804838b                                               // 4
    0xbffff7f0:                                              // 4
    0x00000001 0x00000002 0x00000003 0x00000004              // 5




reader@hacking:~/booksrc $ gcc -g stack_example.c
reader@hacking:~/booksrc $ gdb -q ./a.out
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/tls/i686/cmov/libthread_db.so.1".
(gdb) disass main
Dump of assembler code for function main():
0x08048357 <main+0>: push ebp
0x08048358 <main+1>: mov ebp,esp
0x0804835a <main+3>: sub esp,0x18
0x0804835d <main+6>: and esp,0xfffffff0
0x08048360 <main+9>: mov eax,0x0
0x08048365 <main+14>: sub esp,eax
0x08048367 <main+16>: mov DWORD PTR [esp+12],0x4
0x0804836f <main+24>: mov DWORD PTR [esp+8],0x3
0x08048377 <main+32>: mov DWORD PTR [esp+4],0x2
0x0804837f <main+40>: mov DWORD PTR [esp],0x1
0x08048386 <main+47>: call 0x8048344 <test_function>
0x0804838b <main+52>: leave
0x0804838c <main+53>: ret
End of assembler dump
(gdb) disass test_function()
Dump of assembler code for function test_function:
0x08048344 <test_function+0>: push ebp
0x08048345 <test_function+1>: mov ebp,esp
0x08048347 <test_function+3>: sub esp,0x28
0x0804834a <test_function+6>: mov DWORD PTR [ebp-12],0x7a69
0x08048351 <test_function+13>: mov BYTE PTR [ebp-40],0x41
0x08048355 <test_function+17>: leave
0x08048356 <test_function+18>: ret
End of assembler dump
(gdb)
```

Comment: Where exactly did you break your code execution?

Comment: It's hard to say anything without the compiled code. A compiler could decide not to store `flag` and `buffer`, because they are never read. Please include a disassembly of `test_function` and `main`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`'A'` and `31337` are literals. They have no reason to be placed on the stack.

It would be more interesting for you if you printed out a disassembly of that code block to see exactly what the compiler is emitting. Then you can cross-check with what your stack contains at runtime.

Given that your function has no side-effects, it could be optimized to a no-op.

Here's what I get with your code in an environment I'm more familiar with:

```
Breakpoint 1, test_function (a=1, b=2, c=3, d=4) at t.c:4
4     flag = 31337;
(gdb) disass test_function
Dump of assembler code for function test_function:
   0x080483a4 <+0>: push   %ebp
   0x080483a5 <+1>: mov    %esp,%ebp
   0x080483a7 <+3>: sub    $0x10,%esp
=> 0x080483aa <+6>: movl   $0x7a69,-0x4(%ebp)
   0x080483b1 <+13>:    movb   $0x41,-0xe(%ebp)
   0x080483b5 <+17>:    leave  
   0x080483b6 <+18>:    ret    
End of assembler dump.
(gdb) display $ebp
2: $ebp = (void *) 0xffffcd70
(gdb) display $esp
3: $esp = (void *) 0xffffcd60
(gdb) x/16xw $esp
0xffffcd60: 0xf7e7dcdd  0xf7fa7324  0xf7fa6ff4  0x00000000
0xffffcd70: 0xffffcd88  0x080483e1  0x00000001  0x00000002
0xffffcd80: 0x00000003  0x00000004  0xffffcdf8  0xf7e66cc6
0xffffcd90: 0x00000001  0xffffce24  0xffffce2c  0x00000001
```

Difference with your case, except for the ASM syntax, is that my compiler reserved less slack on the stack, but that's about it.

So, as in your case, the literals end up in the *instruction stream*, not on the stack. The stack address and contents (interpreted as 32bit ints, careful with endianness) of the locals:

```
(gdb)  x/1xw $ebp-4
0xffffcd6c: 0x00000000
(gdb)  x/1xw $ebp-0xe
0xffffcd62: 0x7324f7e7
```

Now lets assign to `flag`:

```
(gdb) n
5     buffer[0] = 'A';
(gdb) x/8xw $esp
0xffffcd60: 0xf7e7dcdd  0xf7fa7324  0xf7fa6ff4  0x00007a69
0xffffcd70: 0xffffcd88  0x080483e1  0x00000001  0x00000002
(gdb)  x/1xw $ebp-4
0xffffcd6c: 0x00007a69
(gdb)  x/1xw $ebp-0xe
0xffffcd62: 0x7324f7e7
```

All good, the right stack slot was updated (`$ebp-4` last 32bit slot in line 1 of the x/8xw).

And lets set the first item of `buffer`:

```
(gdb) n
6   }
(gdb)  x/4x $ebp-0xe
0xffffcd62: 0x41    0xf7    0x24    0x73
(gdb) x/8xw $esp
0xffffcd60: 0xf741dcdd  0xf7fa7324  0xf7fa6ff4  0x00007a69
0xffffcd70: 0xffffcd88  0x080483e1  0x00000001  0x00000002
(gdb)  x/1xw $ebp-4
0xffffcd6c: 0x00007a69
(gdb)  x/1xw $ebp-0xe
0xffffcd62: 0x7324f741
```

All good again. The endianness makes things look a bit strange when viewed as 32bit ints, but it looks fine if you look at it byte by byte.

Comment: Sorry but this answer doesn't make sense.

Comment: I think it does. The `flag = 31337;` line with GCC on x86_64 gets compiled to a `mov` with 31337 as an immediate operand. There is absolutely no reason to see these constants on the stack. If they were string literals (and had not been optimized away), they might appear in the disassembly as pointers into a read-only constant area. No need to put them on the stack either, (unless the compiler starts playing funny tricks on register-starved machines maybe). The  stack contents without the corresponding assembly code is essentially useless.

Comment: Thank you Mat for your clever answer. Then when the author says that stack pointing at 2) which contains 0xbffff89c is the memory for flag, he means literals for memory in stack? And 0xbffff89c is maybe an address where actual data for flag resides?

Comment: But then why the space alocated on stack for local variable int is smaller than space for 10 int array, since all that space does not actually contain data. thanks

Comment: @tomaas: I don't think `flag` is where you marked it `//2`. Look at the address you printed out, it should be at the end of the second line marked `//1`. There is more than enough room for `buffer` 10 bytes needed 28 bytes reserved as far as I can tell - probably to align `buffer` to a nice place. Make sure you step until _after_ the assignments have been run, (and display your stack at each step), it will probably make more sense.

Comment: Everything is well written, exactly as in book. Author claims that  0xbffff89c (which is in // 2) is the memory of flag and it doesnt have anything to do with number 31337. He also says that everything in // 1 is the memory for buffer and I also cant find ´A´ there.

Comment: @tomaas: 31337 should be in 0x080483b9 (pointed by ebp-12 = 0xbffff7dc ) To me, with the information you provide, this is an error. Other error is mov BYTE PTR [ebp-40],0x41 ebp-40 pointing to 0x000000 which would produce a segfault. I suggest you compile that C code and debug it yourself to see the live data. Mat: 'A' and '31337' can be pushed on the stack directly.

Comment: @龚元程: I'm not saying the literals can't be pushed on the stack. I'm saying it is not likely at all that they will be pushed on the stack before function entry (on x86 anyway). They'll appear in the stack after the assignments for sure (unless the compiler optimized them out completely, or keeps them in registers).

Comment: ok I see. As for your edit and tomaas' code there is that recurring problem of moving something to a 0x000000 address "movl $0x7a69,-0x4(%ebp)" ebp-4 = 0x000000 I assumed it was an error in the book, but it appears also in your disassembly. How does that happen?

Comment: `%ebp-4`is `0xffffcd6c`, not 0. 0 is the value stored at `%ebp-4`, which is written to when assigning `flag`.